# Why are my pictures higher than my words in a html page?

Tags: html, formula

I am not familiar with html.I want to show formulas in my blogs.But there is blank between my two lines if I put a picture in one line.Please look at my page [my_web_page](http://neilhappy.blogspot.com/2013/01/linear-sieve-method-for-prime-numbers.html).There is so big blank between the 3 lines than others.I try to change the height of the picture but it was useless.Please tell me where I was wrong or tell me how to show formulas easily in my web pages.Thanks very much!

Comment: put css padding as zero:
add this to your image tag:
style='padding:0px'

Comment: If you are using HTML 4, check this [Link](http://www.unics.uni-hannover.de/nhtcapri/mathematics.html)

Comment: @DigvijayYadav Please look at this. http://neilhappy.blogspot.com/2013/01/linear-sieve-method-for-prime-numbers.html    Is it the best effect?

Comment: You can set the height of the image similar to the font-size. Also keep the padding zero.

Comment: @NeilLuo : did you tried the `margin-bottom:0;vertical-align:bottom;`?

Comment: @krish  Yes,I try it.It is the same to my last method with it.Please look at my page again to say whether it works as you think.Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this style for your img tags

```
padding: 0px;
border: none;
margin: 0px;
vertical-align: bottom;
```

Ex:

```
<img src="your img source here" style="padding:0px;border: none; margin: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;">
```

Comment: Yes,I try it.It is the same to my last method with it.Please look at my page again to say whether it works as you think.Thanks very much!

Comment: @NeilLuo : try with `margin:0px` as i updated in my answer. it should work with your site.

Answer (score 1):

It is blogspot adding padding around your images.
The default style of an image within an article seems to have 8 pixels padding.

If you can edit the html you could try overriding this inline, i.e adding padding:0px; to the style part of the img tag. Please note you will probably also need to remove the margin-bottom: -12px too.

i.e. rather than

```
<img src="http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&amp;chl=p%5Ei*q" style="border: none; margin-bottom: -12px;">
```

try:

```
<img src="http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&amp;chl=p%5Ei*q" style="border: none; padding:0px">
```

Comment: I am sorry  it doesn't work.